# Moving xaml file in solution explorer in WPF MVVM project

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Im new to the MVVM Pattern, i think this question willbe rather easy for you guys.

I created a new wpf project so far and added 3 folders(model, view, view model). I dragged and dropped the mainwindow.xaml file into the view folder and added a button to the xaml so far. At Runtime i get an error cant find "mainwindow.xaml" reference or something like that.
I think i just have to set the path to that file somewhere but i dont know where.

thanks for your help.

Comment: keep in mind that new files which you add to your folders will have different namespaces, eg. MyApp.View.MyView (unless you changed that behavior in VS options I guess). To have your namespaces consistent, you should delete automatically created MainWindow.xaml, add the new one to folder and modify App.xaml accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your App.xaml file will be looking for this file on application startup.

If you are using the MainWindow.xaml file in the same project, change the `StartupUri` in the App.xaml file to `"View\MainWindow.xaml"` and this should resolve the issue.